# How do I override excel conditional formating if one cell contains a value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, highlight, conditional-formatting, vba

I currently have a worksheet where column C changes to red if it is due in the next seven days. I would like to have the row change to a different format if I enter ANY date in column E. I have tried a bunch of different ways but I can only get the E cells to change or the entire worksheet and it seems to ignore the E entry.

Here is a link to the file:
http://mpereaseportfolio.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/6/2/25627115/summer_assingment_schedule.xlsx

Comment: Can you show us examples of your formatting rules?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Select the whole range of data except headers, i.e. `A2:H193`
Now apply a new condition in conditional formatting using the formula

`=$E2<>""`

Select required format

Make sure that condition is at the top and tick "Stop if TRUE" so that other conditions are not  applied

Note that you need exactly that formula including the $

Note also that the formula always refers to the first row of data but will work for the whole range

Comment: worked! Seems the only thing I hadn't tried was excluding the headers and marking stop if true! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try a formula rule such as:

```
=(IFERROR(FIND(" AM",$E2),FIND(" PM",$E2))>0)
```

with applies to `=$A$2:$H$200` or similar